# How do I monkey patch an object's constructor function?

Tags: javascript, monkeypatching

I'd like to monkey patch the constructor for this 'Controller' object. But how do I monkey patch the constructor function so I can still call the original? This is what I've tried.

```
// original
function Controller() {
    this._tag = 'div';
}
Controller.prototype.tag = function() {
    console.log(this._tag);
}

var c = new Controller(); 
c.tag(); // -> 'div', as expected


// patch attempt
var original = Controller;
Controller = function() {
    original.apply(this);
    this._tag = 'patched'; // patch
}

var c = new Controller();
c.tag(); // no method tag, prototype appears wiped...
```

Comment: The grouping operator around the RHS function expression is superfluous. The "constructor" is declared inside another function, so  you can't access it from outside (unless missing code makes it a property of the outer anonymous function or some other object). So if you want to "monkey patch" the constructor (whatever that means), inserting code where you have the comment is the only way.

Comment: @RobG If curious: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch Its pretty straight forward to monkey patch a property or method, but because of the constructor functions special status I'm at a loss. You may be correct that this isn't possible, but I'm not sure about the reasons you state yet. I'll updated the code sample to reflect.

Comment: Telling us how to monkey path a normal method is not a better code sample. It only makes it even harder to see what your real question is.

Comment: couldn't you wrap the constructor and modify the object after it was created? i.e. define a function that calls the saved old constructor and then does its modification and returns the new object. this is commonly done else were with the factory pattern in python.

Comment: @missingno truth. Edited once more.

Comment: @DanD. I believe this is what I've tried. Am I off? Checkout the updated code.

Comment: @TheDeeno—sorry, but I hate meaningless jargon. The term itself offers no hint about what it actually does, much better to say you want to modify the code at run time without affecting the original. Anyhow, the answer is the same. Your amended patch attempt simply replaces one object with another (with a different prototype). That isn't modifying the original code, it's replacing it. An anything that has a reference to the original object still sees the original object, it isn't "patched". The prototype isn't "wiped", the second c is inheriting from a different prototype.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to want to do something like:

```
Constructor.prototype.oldTag = Constructor.prototype.tag;

Constructor.prototype.tag = function() {/* whatever */};
```

Now all instances get the new *tag* method and you can still call *oldTag* if you want (or put it back).

Or perhaps you want to do something like:

```
var oldConstructor = Constructor;

 var Constructor = function () { /* new constructor */ };
 Constructor.prototype = oldConstructor.prototype;
```

So now you have a new constructor with all the old methods. Or do both the above. Just use plain English to say what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. So far, it seems what I'm trying to do isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

The cleaner way is not monkey patching the constructor: put the constructor logic in a separate `init` method and monkey patch / inherit that instead.

```
function Constructor(){
    this.init();
}
Constructor.prototype.init = function(){ /*...*/ };
```

You can also consider building objects with a builder function

```
function make_fancy_obj(){
    var obj = new Constructor();
    obj.foo = 'bar';
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to the original constructor unfortunately. That's why I'm going down this road. Can you do this without modifying the original in my example?

Answer (score 0):

Constructor functions may optionally return a different `this`, which will override whatever is generated by the `new` statement itself - here's your example corrected and annotated:

```js
// original
function Controller() {
    this._tag = 'div';
}
Controller.prototype.tag = function() {
    console.log(this._tag);
}

var c = new Controller(); 
c.tag(); // -> 'div', as expected


// patch attempt
var original = Controller;
Controller = function() {
    const instance = new original(...arguments); //  call the original constructor
    instance._tag = 'patched'; // patch
    return instance; //  return your replacement instance
}

var c = new Controller();
c.tag(); //  works
```

You can try it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mindplay/qc8Lf7ae/